# Installing multiple RPMs, dependency errors?

Tags: centos, rpm, repository

I have a folder on my CentOS box called "RPM" and inside, I have multiple RPMs that I would like to install. Some of these are custom made for special purposes, so there is no chance of getting them online. When I try to install them, either all or once or individually, I get an error about dependency problems. Currently, I am trying to install them by changing directory to the folder and using "rpm -ivh *.rpm". Do I need to create a local repository in order to do this?

Comment: Try `rpm -ivh --nodeps *.rpm`.

Comment: Use `yum` instead to install missing dependencies. Use `for f in *.rpm; yum install '$f"; done`

Answer (score 2):

if your rpms have external dependencies; you should use `yum` (or zypper on opensuse) for the external dependencies. Try:

```
yum install ./*.rpm
```